# How to write web services in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm using Codeigniter version 2. In my project I'm following HMVC pattern. But now I want write REST api web services. For web services I downloaded libraries REST_Controller.php.

After I added libraries create one folder for wirte webservices as per HMVC pattern. After creating function in webservices class I have to write url in this format `http://localhost/project_name/index.php/webservices/login`.

But I don't want url in this format I want in below format `http://localhost/amoeba/webservices/login`. Please suggest me how write web services in Codeigniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to fix your .htaccess file..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|js|system)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```